# How to lookup values for multiple columns in one dataframe from another

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, matching

I have a dataframe (df1) with just movie titles:

```
Movie1              Movie2              Desired
Dinosaur Planet     Screamers           My Favorite Brunette
Immortal Beloved    Strange Relations   Chump Change
Clifford            Lady Chatterley     Invader Zim
```

And another dataframe (df2) with the vector representations of each movie:

```
ID  Year    Title              Genre            Word Vector
1   2003.0  Dinosaur Planet    Documentary      [-0.55423898, -0.72544044, 0.33189204, -0.1720...
2   2004.0  Isle of Man        Sports & Fitness [-0.373265237, -1.07549703, -0.469254494, -0.4...
3   1997.0  Character          Foreign          [-1.57682264, -0.91265768, 2.43038678, -0.2114...
4   1994.0  Get Up & Dance     Sports & Fitness [0.3096168, -0.57186663, 0.39008939, 0.2868615...
```

My goal is to sum movie1 + movie2 in df1 and find the closest matches in df2 using cosine similarity and see if this matches the desired result back in in df1.  To do this, I need to find the vector representation of each movie in df1 and sum the first two columns.

I've written a function that looks up movie vectors from df2

```
def find_movie_vec(movie_str, df):
'''
Given movie string and dataframe with a 'Title' feature, find the movies with titles containing the string
Assumes no ambiguity within the movie string title
'''
row = df[df['Title'].str.contains(movie_str)]
return row.iloc[0]['Word Vector']
```

I'm unsure how to apply it across the dataframe and make a separate column for the vector representation of movie1, movie2, and desired movie.  I tried:

```
df1.apply(find_movie_vec(...))
```

However apply only takes in one argument functions so I was thinking along the lines of:

```
df1.apply(lambda x, y: find_movie_vec(df1['Movie1'], df2) + find_movie_vec(df1['Movie2']), df2))
```

But I'm not sure if this is the cleanest or even correct approach.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you format your data so that we can tell when one column ends the and the next one begins?

Comment: Fixed! I hope that helps